# Serveless not deploying to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless

I'm new to Serverless and lambdas

I'm trying to deploy my serverless functions to AWS but it's showing this error:

[image]

This is my serverless.yml file:

```
service: aws-node-http-api-project
frameworkVersion: "3"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: ap-southeast-1

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /
          method: get
```

I have set the AWS CLI and IAM user.

Not sure if this is related, but in my CloudFormation, it is showing one stack:
[image]

Comment: look like the deployment bucket has been deleted, you can change the service name  from `aws-node-http-api-project` to any name and redeploy your app

Comment: hey, just needed to Delete the stack and redeploy. but thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack was created, but the changeset failed to execute and hence the stack is stuck at the REVIEW_IN_PROGRESS state.

1. Find out why the changeset wasn't executed and fix it.
2. Delete the stack and redeploy.

Comment: Delete the stack and redeploy fix the issue, thanks